# Возможно ли далее в тексте упоминание о мед. центре как о Центре?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

С учетом изложенного, в июне 2006 года был создан костяк из практикующих врачей, и в начале 2007 года зарегистрирован «Многопрофильный медицинский центр "Клиника Профи"».

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно  только  в данном конкретном тексте, например:

**Московский клинический научный центр** (МКНЦ) https://www.mknc.ru/lechenie/otdeleniya/otdelenie/rentgenologicheskoe-otdelenie/

**В нашем Центре** проводятся исследования ВСЕХ органов и систем человека.

Answer (score 1):

Возможен любой вариант (ММЦ, КП, «КП»). Стоит лишь закончить Вашу фразу следующим образом: «...центр "Клиника Профи" (далее — Центр)».